# How can I load an xlsx workbook into R?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have an xlsx workbook on my desktop with existing sheets. I have a dataframe in R that I would like to add to this workbook as a new sheet.

Using `library(openxlsx)` I want to do:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx", isUnzipped=TRUE)
addWorksheet(wb, "New_Sheet")
writeData(wb, "New_Sheet", df)
saveWorkbook(wb, "workbook.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE)
```

however the program fails at the first line:

`wb <- loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx", isUnzipped=TRUE)`

I get the error message:

```
Error in match(sheetrID, file_rIds): object sheetrId not found
```

I also created a dummy file (excel workbook with just two existing sheets and some dummy strings in each sheet) and I get the same error message.

I also tried uninstalling openxlsx and re-installing. No change.

Comment: So, I'll admit I do not use this package often; but I was able to recreate your same issue with a test workbook on my machine. It was confusing to me, because the file is clearly not "zipped," but when I set `isUnzipped = F`, the error message went away and I was able to work with it fine

Comment: Did you actually unzip the file? Or is there a reason you choose `isUnzipped=TRUE`? Because `xlsx` files are actually just fancy zipped files and if you are working with a "normal" xlsx file then it should be zipped.